# How can I search Jira/JQL for code snippets?

Tags: jira, code-snippets, jql

Is there a way I can search Jira for code snippets? I'm collecting snippets that can serve as samples.

I'm using this JQL query - is there a way to target code? Or search for braces/brackets?

```
project IN ('Inbox') AND (text ~ "sample" AND text ~ "example" OR text ~ "code" OR text ~ "snippet") AND created >= startOfYear(-1) and created <= endOfYear()
```